# When was the last time a country acquired territory by buying land from another country?

Tags: land

Reportedly, [U.S. President Donald Trump has proposed for the U.S. to buy Greenland from Denmark](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/aug/15/donald-trump-greenland-purchase-denmark), an idea that has been [rejected by Greenland and Denmark](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/aug/16/greenland-not-for-sale-trump-interest-in-purchasing), with one politician quoting it as *this is not the 19th century*.

In the 19th century, the U.S. [bought Alaska from Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Purchase).  In 1917, [it bought the Danish West Indies from Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_the_Danish_West_Indies) (now called the U.S. Virgin Islands).

Are there any more recent examples or has this idea gone out of fashion in the past century?  When was the last time that a sovereign state acquired land from another sovereign state through purchase, including a transfer of sovereignty?  Is [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territory_purchased_by_a_sovereign_nation_from_another_sovereign_nation) complete?
I mean land purchases that include travel of sovereignty. Otherwise any state-owned real estate purchase would count. –

Related: *[What are some cases where a country bought land from another country, other than the United States?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/47556/1392)*

Comment: Tuvalua, Fiji and other Pacific island nations have been buying land in Australia and elsewhere but I don't think they have sovereignty. I assume you're only interested in land purchase which includes sovereignty(?) There's also the case of Jordan and Saudi Arabia exchanging land in 1965, but I don' think there was any money involved.

Comment: Some people says that China is buying territory in Africa: https://capx.co/china-buys-its-first-african-colony-for-a-meagre-40million/  or https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2018/jul/31/china-in-africa-win-win-development-or-a-new-colonialism

Comment: The answer to your first question is "yes, there are more recent examples", since the link you provide in the third question gives two more recent examples (in 1947 and 1958.)

Comment: 1963: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_annexation_of_German_territory_after_World_War_II

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: That example looks more like the land being held as collateral on a debt than actually being purchased back.

Comment: @gerrit please edit that into the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I thought it was clear from the formulation of "acquired territory", but in any case it's more explicitly stated now.

Comment: The Soviet Union received a lot of money for allowing West Germany to "unify" East Germany: "In return for the Kremlin accepting German reunification, Kohl agreed to pay the costs from withdrawing Soviet troops and resettling them at home. He also promised financial help aimed at stabilizing Soviet finances." https://m.dw.com/en/how-kohl-and-gorbachev-sealed-the-deal-on-german-reunification/a-5788998

Comment: My point was that all the information should be in the question, not on the comments.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Sure, I agree — I considered it was clear from the beginning, but in any case it is clearer now.

Comment: @Jan Ok, but that's still a somewhat different situation, it wasn't really a land purchase.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the most recent compensated border change was a January 1, 2018 change to the Dutch/Belgian border to eliminate enclaves they each had on the other's side of the Meuse (probably due to changes in that river's course, but I haven't checked on that). In this case the compensation can be considered the swapped land.

I could not in fact find a sovereignty transfer involving money since the end of WWII. The basic patterns since then appear to all involve either wars, gifts as part of decolonization, swaps, or in some rare cases, leases. There's probably a "last" one before that, but the war kind of makes things complicated.

Comment: FWIW OP lists a few post WW2 money related purchases in a link in his question, and I added an even later one in the question's comments.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - I saw yours and read the link. It points to WWII-related changes (which again was a line I didn't want to cross for various reasons). However, rereading it, I think it sort of counts. I'll put in in my answer if you don't mind? I still think its not quite what the OP was looking for, in that its almost more of a ransom to get occupied German territory (filled with Germans) back after WWII than a straight land sale.

Comment: @T.E.D. You're correct it has to do with the change of the river. The reason why they swapped a piece of 10 hectares. Is because a hiker found a body on the island, so he called the Dutch police. Because it was on the Dutch side of the border. But they couldn't do anything because it was Belgian soil. But the Belgian police couldn't access it without crossing the Dutch border.

Answer (score 4):

> Tiran is an island within the maritime borders of Saudi Arabia that
> was administered by Egypt in the past. However, sovereignty of the two
> Red Sea islands, Tiran and Sanafir, was ceded officially to Saudi
> Arabia as part of a maritime borders agreement between Egypt and Saudi
> Arabia. The agreement subsequently was approved by the Egyptian
> Parliament and finally ratified by the Egyptian President on 24 June
> 2017 *[Wikipedia:Tiran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiran_Island)*

Apparently, there was no explicit price tag for those islands, but

> Saudi Arabia [is] an ally which has given billions of dollars of aid
> to Egypt. *[reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-egypt-saudi-islands/egypts-sisi-ratifies-deal-ceding-red-sea-islands-to-saudi-arabia-idUSKBN19F0KE?il=0)*

Comment: Did they pay for that?

Comment: @gerrit: Not explicitly, as in they didn't put a price tag on it. But if you count goodwill gained from billions upon billions of foreign aid as a price, then this might be the most recent.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy No, I don't count goodwill.  I mean real money.  Otherwise it becomes much too vague and any land swap may count.

Comment: Hmmm...Given the proposition that someone who gives you billions in aid asking you for some of your land isn't really just a simple request you are free to ignore, I think this might count (sort of). Still you could also say this more fits the modern pattern of it being (at least overtly) a gift. Or perhaps its more like some of Russia's recent annexations, where the giver didn't really have much of an option to say "no".

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Wikipedia list article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territory_purchased_by_a_sovereign_nation_from_another_sovereign_nation) which may answer your question.
The most recent instance given on the article is that of Gwader, a port city in current day Pakistan. It was purchased in 1958 from Oman.